# Save date in Oracle without appending time

Tags: oracle, date, time

I have a date column in oracle. When I'm trying to save data from Spring Boot, it always appends time along with the date. Is there any way I can restrict the time (From Oracle) and only save date in that column without having to do it from Spring Boot. Any help will be very grateful

```
Current data stored: 11/18/2020 5:00:00 AM
Required Format    : 11/18/2020
```

Comment: Oracle doesn't have a date-only column type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know Spring Boot, but - see if you can save *truncated* value, e.g.

```
insert into your_table (date_column) values (TRUNC(sysdate));
                                             -----
                                             this
```

If not, create a `BEFORE INSERT` trigger on that table which will truncate the time part, e.g.

```
create or replace trigger trg_bi_yourt
  before insert on your_table
  for each row
begin
  :new.date_column := trunc(:new.date_column);
end;
/
```

Comment: This will convert the date from `11/18/2020 5:00:00 AM` to `11/18/2020 12:00:00 AM`. It will not remove the time part. It will just truncate it.

Comment: Who said it will "remove" it, @Tejash?

Comment: Yes you mentioned that in your comment that it will truncate. I was mentioning it for just clarity. Otherwise, your answer is correct. +

Comment: For good or bad, Oracle uses the term "truncate" in a context where others would say "round" or "floor".